# How to edit "Tag Info"

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki

I want to edit a "Tag Info" (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stenciljs/info) but I can't find an "edit" button/link. How can I edit it? Unfortunately the Help center search wasn't much help.

Also, is this what is otherwise referred to as "tag wiki"? Because I do have the "Tag Editor" badge so I must have had that permission at one point.

Comment: Go to the page before, [questions tagged stenciljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stenciljs), and then choose "Improve tag info" to suggest an edit.

Comment: Also you need to be a [trusted user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) (20k+ rep) to directly edit tag wikis and excerpts. Until then you can only suggest edits.

Comment: And finally, you earned your "tag editor" badge also for a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7014286).

Comment: Aah, there it is. Would you say this constitutes a bug? Seems weird that it doesn't show up on the actual page.

Comment: Isn't it [right here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8rYb.png)?

Comment: [It wasn't at first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcgBp.png), but now that I have submitted an edit (which needs to be reviewed) it suddenly is. Before I could submit I got a "queue full" error though (whatever that means), maybe that's why the button didn't show up.

Comment: @Thomas "queue full" error results from the, well, the queue being full. Only 500 suggested edits can be pending at any time, and, unfortunately, someone from the company thought it would be a great idea to shove items that can only be reviewed by users with 5K+ rep (read: a small percentage of users) into a fixed-length queue that mostly consists of typo edits, so it might take up to a month to get the edit approved/rejected. Do keep in mind that you are also limited to 5 pending edits at a time, and excerpt + wiki creation counts as 2 edits.

Comment: :D @OlegValter Thanks for the info! I was just trying to guide future visitors to the very active Slack, I usually just answer questions here. Wasn't sure what queue they meant and I still don't understand why they would group all wiki edits...
Anyone else think I should report this as a bug (edit button not on wiki page if queue full)?